# Schwarz integral formula for strip

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, conformal-geometry

Would you please help me solve Exercise 18 of Chapter V in [B. A. Fuchs & B. V. Shabat (1964) *Functions of a complex variable and some of their applications: Vol. 1,* Oxford: Pergamon Press.](http://www.worldcat.org/title/functions-of-a-complex-variable-and-some-of-their-applications-vol-1/oclc/16750611)

> Show that Schwarz's integral formula for the strip $-\pi/2 < y < \pi/2$ is
>   $$f(z) = \frac1{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_+(\xi) + u_-(\xi)}{\cosh(\xi - z)} d\xi - \frac{i \sinh z}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_+(\xi) - u_-(\xi)}{\cosh(\xi - z) \cosh \xi} d\xi$$
>   where $u_+(\xi)$ and $u_-(\xi)$ are the values of the real parts of $f(z)$ on the lines $y = +\pi/2$ and $y = -\pi/2$, respectively.

In other words, $u_+(\xi) =$ Re$f(\xi + \pi i/2),$ and $u_-(\xi) =$ Re$f(\xi - \pi i/2)$ where $\xi$ is real.

One approach is to start with [Schwarz's formula for the upper half-plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_integral_formula#Upper_half-plane),
$$f(z') = \frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u(\xi')}{\xi' - z'} d\xi', $$
where $u(\xi')$ is the value of the real part of $f(z')$ on the $x'$-axis, i.e., $u(\xi') =$ Re$f(\xi' + 0i)$ where $\xi'$ is real, and then use $z' = ie^z,$ which is the conformal map from the strip to the upper half-plane.  That map sends the line $y = \pi/2$, i.e., the top boundary of the strip, from $y = \infty + \pi i/2$ to $y = -\infty + \pi i/2$ to the negative $x'$-axis in the half plane from $-\infty + 0i$ to $0 + 0i$, and $y = -\pi/2$ from $y = -\infty - \pi i/2$ to $y = \infty - \pi i/2$ to the positive $x'$-axis from $0 + 0i$ to $\infty + 0i$.  As a result, we have to separate the integral into two parts,
$$f(z') = \frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{u(\xi')}{\xi' - z'} d\xi' + \frac1{\pi i} \int_0^\infty \frac{u(\xi')}{\xi' - z'} d\xi',$$
before we substitute for $z'$ and $\xi'.$  After substitution, $u$ becomes $u_+$ in the first integral and $u_-$ in the second, and the limits of integration change to $-\infty$ and $\infty$ with proper attention, or course, to the direction of integration.  In the first integral, $\xi' = ie^{\xi + i\pi/2} = -e^\xi;$ in the second, $\xi' = ie^{\xi - i\pi/2} = e^\xi.$

After substitution and rearrangement, I get something other than the requested formula:
$$f(z) = \frac1{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_+(\xi) + u_-(\xi)}{\cosh(\xi - z)} d\xi + \frac i{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_+(\xi) - u_-(\xi)}{\cosh(\xi - z)} e^{\xi - z} d\xi.$$

A second approach is to derive Poisson's integral formula for the strip, and then show that that formula is the real part of Schwarz's integral formula for the strip.  I have proofs of Poisson's integral formula for the disc and upper half-plane, but I do not know how to start the derivation for the strip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with NOT $$
f(z^\prime) = \frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u(\xi^\prime)}{\xi^\prime - z^\prime} d\xi^\prime$$
BUT $$
f(z^\prime) = \frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(\xi^\prime)\left(\frac{1}{\xi^\prime - z^\prime}-\frac{\xi^\prime}{{\xi^\prime}^2+1}\right) d\xi^\prime.
$$
This is the formula for a function with $\operatorname{Im }f(i)=0.$

Of course we separate the integral into two parts,
$$
f(z^\prime) = \frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^0 u(\xi^\prime)\frac{\xi^\prime z^\prime +1}{\xi^\prime - z^\prime}\frac{d\xi^\prime}{{\xi^\prime}^2+1} +\frac1{\pi i} \int_0^\infty u(\xi^\prime)
\frac{\xi^\prime z^\prime +1}{\xi^\prime - z^\prime}\frac{d\xi^\prime}{{\xi^\prime}^2+1}. \tag{1}
$$ 
After substitution, the first integral will be
\begin{align}
&\frac1{\pi i} \int_\infty^{-\infty} u_+(\xi)\frac{-ie^\xi e^z +1}{-e^\xi -i e^z}\frac{-e^\xi}{e^{2\xi}+1} d\xi\\
&=\frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u_+(\xi)\frac{(ie^\xi e^z -1)(e^\xi -i e^z)}{(e^\xi +i e^z)(e^\xi -i e^z)}\frac{1}{e^{\xi}+e^{-\xi }} d\xi\\
&=\frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u_+(\xi)\frac{i(e^\xi +e^{-\xi}) +(e^z -e^{-z})}{e^{\xi-z} + e^{z-\xi }}\frac{1}{e^{\xi}+e^{-\xi }} d\xi\\
&=\frac1{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u_+(\xi)\frac{\cosh \xi  -i\sinh z}{\cosh(\xi-z)}\frac{1}{\cosh\xi} d\xi,
\end{align}
since $\xi ^\prime=ie^{\xi +i\pi/2}=-e^\xi $ and $z^\prime=ie^z.$

Similarly the second integral in $(1)$ will be $$
\frac1{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u_-(\xi)\frac{\cosh \xi +i\sinh z}{\cosh(\xi-z)}\frac{1}{\cosh\xi} d\xi.
$$

**EDIT.**
Schwarz's formula for the unit disc is the following:
$$
F(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\xi|=1}\frac{\xi +z}{\xi -z}U(\xi )\frac{d\xi }{\xi }+i\operatorname{Im }F(0).
$$
If $\operatorname{Im }F(0)=0$, of course it will be $$
F(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\xi|=1}\frac{\xi +z}{\xi -z}U(\xi )\frac{d\xi }{\xi }.
$$
We start with this expression. 
Using substitution $$
z=\varphi (z^\prime)=\frac{z^\prime -i}{z^\prime +i},$$
we have \begin{align}
\frac{\xi +z}{\xi -z}&=\frac{\varphi (\xi ^\prime)+\varphi (z^\prime) }{\varphi (\xi ^\prime)-\varphi (z^\prime) }=\frac{\xi ^\prime z^\prime +1}{i(\xi ^\prime-z^\prime)},\\
\frac{d\xi }{i\xi }&=\frac{2}{{\xi ^\prime}^2+1}d\xi ^\prime, \\
F(\varphi (z^\prime))&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\xi ^\prime z^\prime +1}{i(\xi ^\prime-z^\prime)}U(\varphi (\xi^\prime))\frac{2}{{\xi ^\prime}^2+1}d\xi\\
&=\frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty U(\varphi (\xi'))\left(\frac{1}{\xi^\prime - z^\prime}-\frac{\xi^\prime}{{\xi^\prime}^2+1}\right) d\xi^\prime.
\end{align}
Writing $F(\varphi (z^\prime))=f(z^\prime),$ $ U(\varphi (\xi ^\prime))=u(\xi ^\prime)$, We get $$f(z^\prime)=\frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(\xi^\prime)\left(\frac{1}{\xi^\prime - z^\prime}-\frac{\xi^\prime}{{\xi^\prime}^2+1}\right) d\xi^\prime
,$$
which is the formula we have used above.

Comment: Would you please help me understand better your solution: How did you know what integral to start with and what is its significance?  What is the significance that Im$f(i) = 0?$  Is my approach wrong because the [Schwarz integral formula for the half plane requires an additional condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_integral_formula#Upper_half-plane) that is not required for the strip?

Comment: A function $f(z)$ defined by the requested formula satisfies $\operatorname{Im }f(0)=0,$ since $$
f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_+(\xi )+u_-(\xi )}{\cosh \xi }d\xi$$ is real. So if we start with $$f(z^\prime) = \frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u(\xi^\prime)}{\xi^\prime - z^\prime} d\xi^\prime\tag{1}$$
and use the substitution $z^\prime = ie^z$, RHS of $(1)$ should be modified to satify $\operatorname{Im }f(i)=0$, since $z^\prime=i$ for $z=0$.

Comment: Note that $$
\operatorname{Im }f(i)=\operatorname{Im }\left\{ \frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u(\xi^\prime)}{\xi^\prime - i} d\xi^\prime \right\}=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(\xi^\prime)\frac{\xi ^\prime}{{\xi^\prime}^2 +1} d\xi^\prime \ne 0,
$$
in general. See also EDIT.